# Repurpose PPC Mac Mini as video chat/fileserver/backup system?

Tags: mac-mini, conferencing, file-server

I am about to replace an ageing G4 PPC Mac Mini with the latest model and have a couple of thoughts on repurposing the old hardware; I'm looking for advice/recommendations as to the ideas being worthwhile - or should I just forget it and build a custom PC to suit my desires?

**1. Video chat**

For a long time I've wanted a small computer to use for video chat with family members across the world, that I can situate next to the HDTV and with a wireless keyboard/mouse so I can video chat from the couch. To me this would be a no-brainer for the Mini; however I vaguely remember a rumor about the Mini's DVI port not having all the signals required to drive a HDMI port. Is this true?

Any recommendations on the wireless keyboard?

**2. Fileserver/Backup system**

I am also looking for a home-wide fileserver and backup solution.  The configuration I have been thinking about is a "box" attached to the Mini with a set of fixed disks configured as a RAID setup for handling file serving and media center duties. In the box I also want at least one drive bay for a removable hard drive so I can do backups of the RAID system and move them offsite.

So far I haven't found any single boxes that seems to fit those requirements and also plugs into firewire. I'm not too keen on plugging things into the Mini's USB ports other than keyboard/mouse. So I am looking for any recommendations in that department as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the Logitech diNovo Edge as a wireless keyboard.

Comment: At you answered part of my question!